# how to reverse this operation?

Tags: php, programming-languages

```
<?php

echo (2884284 >> 16), '<br>'; // = 44

echo ((2884284 >> 16) & 0xFFFF), '<br>'; // 44
```

from the above i got 44

so how can i retrive from 44 to  2884284 ???

Answer (score 9):

You cant.  You are destroying data by doing the shift.

Answer (score 3):

To expand on mhughes answer:

2884284 in binary is:

```
1011000000001010111100
```

When you shift to the right, bits to the right are cut off, and bits on the left are filled with 0. So `2884284 >> 16` becomes:

```
0000000000000000101100
```

...which, as you mentioned, is 44. Notice this is the same as dividing by 2^16 and rounding down. The reverse operation is `<<`, or bit shift left. It cuts off bits on the left and fills in bits on the right with zero. But `44 << 16` is:

```
1011000000000000000000
```

...that is, you lost the data from the truncated bits. This number is 2883584, which maybe is close enough. Note this is the same as multiplying by 2^16.